# How to contribute a button to the workbench window main toolbar

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

[image]

Please see above snapshot. I want to add commands into toolbar 1, but they go into toolbar2.
Here is my plugin.xml,

```xml
<menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
         <toolbar
               id="my.toolbar">
            <command
                  commandId="my.open"
                  label="Open"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="my.save"
                  label="Save"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="my.exit"
                  label="Exit"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
```

I know the locationURI or the toolbar id is not correct. But I don't know the ID of toolbar 1.
Please help me have a look at the issue.

Comment: You're definition looks correct.  What's in the text box at the end of the main toolbar?

Comment: It is "Quick Access". I'm using the eclipse package "eclipse-rcp-juno-win32" and create a RCP program by wizard. The main tool bar is there after the wizard is completed.

Comment: Are you persisting state between sessions, a la `org.eclipse.ui.application.IWorkbenchConfigurer.setSaveAndRestore(boolean)`?

Comment: No, I never call setSaveAndrestore(). My RCP program is created by the "New Plug-in Project" wizard. You can reproduce my issue easily.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the system, the menuContribution is not being applied at the correct time during window creation.  You can open a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=UI

If you were to set save & restore to true, on the restore it would probably be in the correct place (but it still should get fixed).